# When to use coroutineScope vs supervisorScope?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Can someone explain what exactly is the difference between these two?

When do you use one over the other?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The best way to explain the difference is to explain the mechanism of `coroutineScope`. Consider this code:

```
suspend fun main() = println(compute())

suspend fun compute(): String = coroutineScope {
    val color = async { delay(60_000); "purple" }
    val height = async<Double> { delay(100); throw HttpException() }
    "A %s box %.1f inches tall".format(color.await(), height.await())
}
```

`compute()` "fetches" two things from the network (imagine the `delay`s are actually network operations) and combines them into a string description. In this case the first fetch is taking a long time, but succeeds in the end; the second one fails almost right away, after 100 milliseconds.

What behavior would you like for the above code?

1. Would you like to `color.await()` for a minute, only to realize that the other network call has long failed?
2. Or perhaps you'd like the `compute()` function to realize after 100 ms that one of its network calls has failed and immediately fail itself?

With `supervisorScope` you're getting 1., with `coroutineScope` you're getting 2.

The behavior of 2. means that, even though `async` doesn't itself throw the exception (it just completes the `Deferred` you got from it), the failure immediately cancels its coroutine, which cancels the parent, which then cancels all the other children.

This behavior can be weird when you're unaware of it. If you go and catch the exception from `await()`, you'll think you've recovered from it, but you haven't. The entire coroutine scope is still being cancelled. In some cases there's a legitimate reason you don't want it: that's when you'll use `supervisorScope`.

### A Few More Points

Let's make two changes to our program: use `supervisorScope` as discussed, but also swap the order of awaiting on child coroutines:

```
suspend fun main() = println(compute())

suspend fun compute(): String = supervisorScope {
    val color = async { delay(60_000); "purple" }
    val height = async<Double> { delay(100); throw HttpException() }
    "The box is %.1f inches tall and it's %s".format(height.await(), color.await())
}
```

Now we first await on the short-lived, failing `height` coroutine. When run, this program produces an exception after 100 ms and doesn't seem to await on `color` at all, even though we are using `supervisorScope`. This seems to contradict the contract of `supervisorScope`.

What is actually happening is that `height.await()` throws the exception as well, an event distinct from the underlying coroutine throwing it.

Since we aren't handling the exception, it escapes from the top-level block of `supervisorScope` and makes it complete abruptly. This condition — distinct from a child coroutine completing abruptly — makes `supervisorScope` cancel all its child coroutines, but it still  awaits on all of them to complete.

So let's add exception handling around the `await`s:

```
suspend fun compute(): String = supervisorScope {
    val color = async { delay(60_000); "purple" }
    val height = async<Double> { delay(100); throw Exception() }
    try {
        "The box is %.1f inches tall and it's %s".format(height.await(), color.await())
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        "there was an error"
    }
}
```

Now the program does nothing for 60 seconds, awaiting the completion of `color`, just as described.

Or, in another variation, let's remove exception handling around `await`s, but make the `color` coroutine handle the `CancellationException`, wait for 2 seconds, and then complete:

```
suspend fun compute(): String = coroutineScope {
    val color = async {
        try {
            delay(60_000); "purple"
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            withContext(NonCancellable) { delay(2_000) }
            println("color got cancelled")
            "got error"
        }
    }
    val height = async<Double> { delay(100); throw Exception() }
    "The box is %.1f inches tall and it's %s".format(height.await(), color.await())
}
```

This does nothing for 2.1 seconds, then prints "color got cancelled", and then completes with a top-level exception — proving that the child coroutines are indeed awaited on even when the top-level block crashes.

Answer (score 49):

I think [Roman Elizarov explain it quite in details](https://medium.com/@elizarov/explicit-concurrency-67a8e8fd9b25), but to make it short:

Coroutines create the following kind of hierarchy:

- Parent Coroutine

  - Child coroutine 1
  - Child coroutine 2
  - ...
  - Child coroutine N

Assume that "Coroutine i" fails. What do you want to happen with its parent?

If you want for its parent to also fail, use `coroutineScope`. That's what structured concurrency is all about.

But if you don't want it to fail, for example child was some kind of background task which can be started again, then use `supervisorScope`.

Comment: Oh i see.. So its just that simple. So lets say i have a code which could throw an exception and lets say i've mitigated it by usibg try and catch. If i use coroutineScope then, this exception will still be passed to my parent coroutine? Is that correct?

Comment: Btw thanks for the article link. I've not seen that during my research. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Short and to the point. Upvoting!!

Answer (score 19):

`coroutineScope` -> The **scope and all its children** fail whenever any of the children fails

`supervisorScope` -> The **scope and all its children** do **NOT** fail whenever any of the children fails

Answer (score 7):

As @N1hk mentioned, if you use `async` the order of calling `await` matters. And if you're depending on a result from both `asynch..await` blocks, then it makes sense to cancel as early as possible so that's not an ideal example for `supervisorScope`

The difference is more apparent when using `launch` and `join`:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    supervisorScope {
        val task1 = launch {
            println("Task 1 started")
            delay(100)
            if (true) throw Exception("Oops!")
            println("Task 1 completed!")
        }
        val task2 = launch {
            println("Task 2 started")
            delay(1000)
            println("Task 2 completed!")
        }

        listOf(task1, task2).joinAll()
        println("Finished waiting for both tasks")
    }

    print("Done!")
}
```

With `supervisorScope`, the output would be:

```
Task 1 started
Task 2 started
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Oops!
...
Task 2 completed!
Finished waiting for both tasks
Done!
```

With `coroutineScope` the output would be just:

```
Task 1 started
Task 2 started
```

Answer (score 5):

**CoroutineScope** -> Cancel whenever any of its children fail.

**SupervisorScope** -> If we want to continue with the other tasks even when one fails, we go with the supervisorScope. A supervisorScope won’t cancel other children when one of them fails.

**Here is a useful link for understanding of coroutine in details:**

https://blog.mindorks.com/mastering-kotlin-coroutines-in-android-step-by-step-guide