# How can a method that is called in multiple asynchronous coroutines be called only once?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

On the main screen, 3 async requests:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
  try {
    val requestAccountDeffer = async { requestAccounts() }
    val updateStatusDeffer = async { updateVerificationStatus() }
    val requestProfileDeffer = async { requestProfile() }
    requestAccountDeffer.await()
    updateStatusDeffer.await()
    requestProfileDeffer.await()
  } catch (exception: Throwable) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

My backend uses an accessToken, which expires for a minute, and a refreshToken to update it. Before each request, the accessToken is checked to see if it has expired and is updated if necessary.

The problem is that if the accessToken expires at the start of the main screen, then the method to update it will be called three times (in each async {...} block), and the backend will return an error when trying to update the accessToken. How to make that only one asynс block calls to update the token?

I can synchronously update token before calling async blocks, but it seems to me that this is not quite the right solution.

**Update**

Current accessToken and refreshToken are stored in sharefPrefs.

1. Before starting a retrofit request, check if the token has expired.
2. If it is expired, then call the retrofit method to update the token, and I get a response.
3. Save new tokens in the sharefPrefs.
4. Execute the main request with the updated access token.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're worried that if the access token expires before each of the three requests are made, then each request would attempt to update the access token independently. How are you sharing/updating the current token between coroutines? Ideally, it shouldn't be possible for multiple coroutines to simultaneously update a shared resource.

Comment: If you want to prevent all requests from independently accessing or modifying the current token, you will probably have to encapsulate your access logic within some sort of concurrency-limiting mechanism, i.e. a lock (the basic idea is the same whether the token is stored in memory or on disk via `SharedPreferences`)

Comment: check out my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77206302/11671900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid concurrent updates to shared resources (in this case, the access token) by using Kotlin's asynchronous [`Mutex`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/index.html):

> `interface Mutex` ([`Mutex.kt`](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/sync/Mutex.kt))
>
> Mutual exclusion for coroutines.
> <sub>[kotlinx-coroutines-core](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/index.html) / [kotlinx.coroutines.sync](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/index.html) / [Mutex](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/index.html)</sub>

Essentially, you can lock the resource, suspending if necessary, check if it has expired and potentially renew it, and then return the current value.

```
private lateinit var currentToken: AccessToken
private val tokenMutex = Mutex()

suspend fun getToken(): AccessToken {
    return tokenMutex.withLock {
        if (currentToken.isExpired) {
            // Refresh token
            val newToken = ...

            // Update the stored token
            currentToken = newToken
            
            newToken
        } else currentToken
    }
}
```

Then instead of accessing the current token value directly, you use this function as a sort of get-or-update proxy instead.

`Mutex`'s functionality is equivalent to [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html), except that it suspends instead of blocking and is non-reentrant.

---

That said, I don't think there would be anything wrong with the alternative approach of updating the token before making the three requests.

---

Side note: there is absolutely no reason to launch three `Deferred` jobs and immediately await them; this is a very good use case for [coroutine scopes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#coroutine-scope):

```
coroutineScope {
    launch { requestAccounts() }
    launch { updateVerificationStatus() }
    launch { requestProfile() }
}
```

This call will suspend until all child jobs of the newly-created scope are complete, and will fail as soon as one of the children throws an exception.

If this behavior isn't what you want, you can use a [`SupervisorScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html) instead (see also [When to use `coroutineScope` vs `supervisorScope`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577907/when-to-use-coroutinescope-vs-supervisorscope)), or install your own exception handler.