# What is the proper non-blocking way to refresh access token in kotlin multiplatform?

Tags: kotlin, async-await, refresh, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

We have 2 projects (iOS and Android) which depends on shared module built using KMP(Kotlin Multiplatform), network client Ktor.
When we get an issue that access token is expired we need to start a process of asynchronously refreshing that token.
Our current implementation uses blocking mechanism as well but I guess there may be some pitfalls:
If we block every thread and wait until refresh is finished we can cause that there are no threads to execute such refreshing task and refreshing won't be performed at all, am I right?

What is the proper way to do that using coroutines in non blocking manner (instead of runBlocking, Mutex, Lock) like here:
[Mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63466732/how-can-a-method-that-is-called-in-multiple-asynchronous-coroutines-be-called-on)